# ActionScript Mimic Different Time Zone

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an app that has many references to a comparison function in my DateUtilities to see if two dates are on the same day. Unfortunately, the logical approach is used a couple hundred times in my application. Now I see that in unusual circumstances a user may want to count an event that starts at midnight of some day as an event that happens on the physical previous day. So, for instance, they may have games at 9PM, 10PM, 11PM, and 12PM. But my baked-in logic would always say that 12PM is the next day.

The only approach I can think of is to temporarily fool the program into thinking the UTC offset is different by 1 hour then return it to the usual offset once evaluation of same day events is completed.

Any suggestions on how to temporarily change the perceived offset? I know that ActionScript has a timeZoneOffset but that's read only. My attempts so far have failed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to recreate your problem? Is the correct order expected to be 12PM, 9PM, 10PM.? As they (user) selects each time, do you put into an array that can be later **sorted** by some function into 12,9,10? (2) Why can't `timeZoneOffset` be used to adjust (plus or minus) your own numbers. (3) Why not use 24hr clock for background processing (but the user interface displays that as 12 hour AM/PM?

Comment: I'm sorry, My example was a typo. The problem is 9PM, 10PM, 11PM and 12AM. I'd like to entertain suggestions into how I can temporarily count 12AM of the following day as a game that occurs on the previous day.

Comment: Maybe you could account for the 12am slot for the next day in your logic when doing the checks? I think the main issue you have at the moment is how to assign the 12am slot to BOTH days so that they turn up on comparison checks for boths days.